# HaShem's Name After The Letters of ו / כ / ל / ב

Tags: grammar-dikduk, divine-names

Not sure if this was asked before...

**Statement:** When the letters of ו / כ / ל / ב ,  (which spells the word “and Kalayv”) come in front the names of HaShem of:  אֲ-דֹנָי   /   אֱ-לֹהֵי   /   אֱ-לֹהִים
(Including when written as: יְ-יָ or   יְ-הֹ-וָ-ה) 
the Chataf Patach vowel under the א is hidden (and not said).

**Question:** However, we find that there are 7 exceptions throughout TaNaCh that don't follow this rule, such as in the phrase: הוֹדוּ לַאֲדֹנֵי הָאֲדֹנִים (Tehillim 136:3).  When this occurs, there will be a Chataf Patach vowel under the “א” and it is pronounced. In addition, we also find that this rule sometimes applies even when not referring to HaShem as in, “וְאֵלְכָה לַאדֹנִי...”(Breisheet 24:56)

Does anyone have a reason stated for this anomaly?

Comment: Can you list all seven examples?

Comment: There are nine examples, in seven pesukim. They're listed in עין המסורה to [Tehillim 135:5](https://www.mgketer.org/tanach/27/135/5). They're not all referring to God, though.

Comment: Editing in the seven exceptions will help people help you: it'll give them an idea where to look in commentaries.

Comment: I was reading Yosef Ofer's book, where he made an important point. Masoretes didn't always cite a rule, but they documented the tradition that they judged as correct - which could have had of course exceptions. In later generations many wanted to make up new rules and "correct" them, or give new interpretations to the exceptions that could have easily been false. Therefore, if Ben Asher says that it is so (and you accept his authority), you can't always cite a rule for the particular orthography.

Comment: See Minchat Shair Comment here: https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.135.5?lang=bi&with=Minchat%20Shai&lang2=en

ואדנינו. כל לשון אדון ואלוה שרכב עליו בוכ"ל הוא רפי האל"ף ולא מפיק כגון באדני. באלהים. ואדני. ואלהים. ואלהיו. כאדני. כאלהים. לאדני. לאלהים. בר מן ז' מפקין אל"ף וסימנהון בתילים סי' קל"ו במ"ג וזה אחד מהם: